# Making ui datepicker header collapsible

Tags: jquery-ui, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to take the ui-datepicker-header and convert it to an accordion. It actually works (sort of). I want to hide notes here for the user to reveal if they choose.

I need the accordion to be collapsed when the page opens. What I have always open expanded despite using these parameters:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-header').accordion({
      active: false, 
      collapsible: true, 
      autoHeight: false, 
      event: "click"
});
```

Once the page renders I see the arrow image is correct but I need click the header twice to get it to close. After this it works as expected.

Here's a fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mv5492/PuWWS/17/

Since these are both ui components I figured this would work fine.

Thanks in advance!
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `$('.ui-datepicker-header').accordion(...` declaration *below* the `$('.ui-datepicker-header').append()` statement that appends the text to the header.

This means that the `aria-` tags will be applied to the text under .ui-datepicker-header, and the text will be set to `display: none` when the page loads.

Comment: Beautiful! It works just like I was hoping. Thanks for the help and explaination. updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mv5492/PuWWS/18/